# how to set fpga attribute?

Tags: fpga, pins

i am trying to turn a led on and off by fpga but IO properties of reg(s) is set to 'OFF' which is output flip flop!

My question is that how can I set IO register to NO in ISE?
I have tried this :

inst "led_error" IOB = false;

but nothing changed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to help based on so little and scattered information, so please consider making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  However, don't think of attributes for a simple design like this.  Whether the output has Output Flip Flop (OFF) is an implementation detail, that the FPGA tool can choose to use depending on timing, which for a LED does not matter.  So write the design, and simulate it so you can see it works, and it will then most likely also work in HW.

Answer (score 1):

There is a routing options to push FFs into the pads which you can switch on or off. (In ISE it is a stand alone placement option, I have not found it in Vivado yet.)

BUT!!!!
In a previous question you mentioned that two of your the I/Os (which happen to have the 'OFF' attribute) don't work. The OFF is unlikely to be the source of that problem. All what he routing tool did was take an *existing* internal FF and move it into the pad to improve I/O timing.

I suggest you start looking elsewhere why your output does not work. e.g. check the clock which goes to the FFs which drive the outputs.

---

I re-awakened my old ISE program and as expected found it under the map settings (Right click on "Map" and select "Process Properties..."):

[image]

Comment: I have found source of the problem I was using INOUT in one of internal module! which caused all of the IOs stop working some how!Is there any way to use INOUT not at the top of the hierarchy ? And can you tell me more about pack I/O Registers / Latches into IOBs? what it means? where should I use them?

Comment: Packing register in the IOB means there is no path delay from the register (which may be at the other side of the die) to the I/O pad. This makes that if you have multiple outputs they will all change at the `same` time. With most interfaces you want this so I just let the tool pack any FFs into the IO block. And NO! Xilinx and other FPGAs no longer allow INOUT inside a design as tri-state buses inside chips are a big no, no, these days.

Comment: so you say there is no way to make my way around it and i should design a circuit to do inout job for me ?

Comment: You can have INOUT only at the top level, for the FPGA I/O pins. There is NO workaround inside the FPGA. It can't be done at all!

Comment: new updates, I may have found the reason! The source of problem was the specific pin that I was using! I have changed the pin and problem solved. Though, I did not understand why using that pin had this huge impact on the whole system!

Comment: And because of the rest won't go wrong, using INOUT do not make any troubles. fill free to use it any where of your design.